# Python requests.get() VS Powershell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri

Tags: python, powershell

I was measuring page load time for my site. I used Python `requests.get(url)`method which once in a while gives me this huge response times (12+ seconds).  but when I try using PowerShell, `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri`, it never exceeds 1 second.

I was wondering what the difference are between these two methods is and what the best approach would be.

Python:

```python
r = requests.get(url)
r.elapsed.total_seconds()
```

PowerShell:

```bsh
$result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url }
$result1.TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: Good question; But pls make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour.

Comment: Difference is that one is implemented in python, and the other in .NET

Comment: understood they are both different frameworks.  why the difference in the response time?  are they measuring different things?

Comment: We can't possible debug random web request delays on your computer with the information you provided here.

Answer (score 1):

I did try both for google.com

```
$result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://google.com" }
$result1.TotalMilliseconds
```

635 is the result

I tried a different method for execution time :

```
import requests
import time
start = time.time()
r = requests.get("http://google.com")
print(" %s seconds" % (time.time() - start))
```

result :  0.4560821056365967 seconds

I tried with print(r.elapsed.total_seconds()) also with similar results

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://google.com")
print(r.elapsed.total_seconds())
```

I am not finding the drastic difference you said , and in subsequent executions the values are quite similar

Answer (score 0):

- There is something called as dns cache in windows which would be used by powershell whenever you simulate a call to an `URL`.
- **Example:** Assume `x.company.com` is the url which you are trying to hit. When you use invoke-webrequest it will resolve the address in dns cache.
- Flush the cache and see the difference. You will see the same time for Invoke-`webrequest` and python's `request.get(url)`